# IVF for crossbreeding animals

Tags: animals, kilayim-forbidden-mixture

The prohibition that one gets מלקות for in the case of כלאי בהמה is only כמכחול בשפופרת. It is in fact permitted to have the two animals "live" in the same stall in the expectation that they will breed.

What about IVF? Is it permissible to use in vitro fertilization to cross breed an animal? Why or why not?

Comment: What about artificial insemination?

Comment: That is the same thing as IVF.

Comment: you're saying it's the same technique? or that you believe halachically they should have the same ruling?

Comment: They are two words for the same thing

Comment: Ah. Not really. From wiki 'Artificial insemination is the deliberate introduction of sperm into a female's cervix or uterine cavity for the purpose of achieving a pregnancy through in vivo fertilization by means other than sexual intercourse.' IVF is 'a process of fertilisation where an egg is combined with sperm in vitro ("in glass")'

Comment: Gotcha. Since neither of them are a מעשה ביאה but directly result in fertilization, the question I asked would apply to both.